# Detect FF4 using JS objects

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm currently working on a site that detects the browser version by checking for various JS objects:

```
var is = { 
  ff: window.globalStorage, 
  ie: document.all && !window.opera, 
  ie6: !window.XMLHttpRequest, 
  ie7: document.all && window.XMLHttpRequest && !XDomainRequest && !window.opera, 
  ie8: document.documentMode==8, 
  opera: Boolean(window.opera), 
  chrome: Boolean(window.chrome), 
  safari: window.getComputedStyle && !window.globalStorage && !window.opera 
}
```

However this doesn't work in FireFox 4. Does anyone know what objects to check for, when you want to detect FF4?

Comment: Why do you want to detect Firefox 4 in particular?

Comment: That example won't even work in any version of firefox as is. window.globalStorage is an object and will evaluate as FALSE if empty, which it usually is, javascript:alert(window.globalStorage?'true':'false') - instead you'd have to test via isNaN(window.globalStorage) - try javascript:alert(isNaN(window.globalStorage)?'false':'true') on firefox, chrome, opera and IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for something that was introduced with Gecko 2.0, such as selection.modify:

```
window.globalStorage && window.getSelection().modify
```

and window.globalStorage won't return all versions of FF, as it requires Gecko 1.8.1 / FF2

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of overhead calling so many global objects and it looks very, very complex. Why not use something like jQuery to check browser versions or even just the simple Navigator object?

[Navigator Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use modernizer, it's a javascript library designed to handle browser version and trigger fallback

http://www.modernizr.com/